# ListView doesn't update until a key is pressed on the simulator

Tags: java, android, listview, refresh

I'm working on one of my first Android apps in which I load some JSON from the web and, after parsing, display the data in a `ListView`. When the app first launches, the `ListView` is empty. After the data is loaded, it's quite full. However, even while using `notifyDataSetChanged()` on my adapter, the `ListView` doesn't refresh and show the newly-loaded data until I press a key on the simulator's keyboard.

This is the processing I perform. I download the JSON, parse it, then my code looks like this - now, nothing shows at all, not even when pressing a key:

```
JSONArray jObject = new JSONArray(new2);
int l = jObject.length();
downloadedArrayOfStrings = new String[jObject.length()];

for(int i = 0; i < l; i++){
    Log.v("i", ""+i);
    jObject.getJSONObject(i).getString("category").toString();
}

ArrayList<String> lst = new ArrayList<String>();
lst.addAll(Arrays.asList(downloadedArrayOfStrings));
newAdapter = new MobileArrayAdapter(this, lst, downloadedArrayOfStrings);
newAdapter.setJSONArray(jObject);
setListAdapter(newAdapter);
```

Any ideas as to why this is happening, and how to fix it?

Comment: It's almost impossible to know what's happening without any context. Please post the relevant code and any logcat errors.

Comment: I would set the adapter only after having the data from the web. When I change the list items and call notifyDataChanged rarelly works.

Comment: I tried what you said Nuno, now my code after downloading looks like this: (edited above) - and it's not showing anything

Answer (score 0):

you should reassign the `ListAdapter` to the `ListView` when the list needs update. The `notifyDataSetChanged()` doesn't work properly with `ListAdapter` and was designed to used with `CursorAdapter`. you can also try using `invalidateViews()` before you try what I said above. `invalidateViews()` basically will rebuild your `ListView`.

Comment: Tried what? can you put some code...where you reassigning the `ListAdapter`?

Comment: I'm reassigning the ListAdapter after the download finishes, in the code above. That code gets executed after an HttpURLConnection finishes on a different thread. I tried getListView().invalidateViews() and it's still blank.

Comment: Try `getListView().setListAdapter(new MobileArrayAdapter(this,lst, downloadedArrayOfStrings));`

Comment: Still nothing. ListView is empty. Just to verify - the data is definitely there and parsed correctly. I've verified that many times. Before all these changes, the data would be displayed correctly only after a key press on the simulator's keyboard. Now, nothing is displayed no matter what. I'm so confused because the code looks correct and I've been staring at it for hours. Edit: to be clear, this code is called from an AsyncTask instance. Could that have anything to do with it? That I'm trying to refresh the listView from a different thread?

Comment: can you post some more code, I want to see where you are creating `ListView` and from where you are trying to update it.

Comment: Was this ever resolved?  I'm having a very similar problem with the ListView not updating when calling from a background thread via runOnUiThread.